# Save results of multiple requests into array

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I was trying to make multiple API requests and store responses into the array.

Array stayed empty because I didn't know about async behavior of for loop.

```js
const results = [];
          
for (let i = 0; i < apiUrls.length; i++) {    
  apiCall(apiUrls[i], res => {
    results.push(res);
  });
} 

console.log(results) // []
```

So I rewrite it to:

```js
const results = []

async function makeApiCalls () {
  for (const apiUrl in apiUrls) {
    const res = await apiCall(apiUrl)
    results.push(res)
  }
  
  console.log(results) // [data, someData, otherData...] 
}

makeApiCalls()
```

It works! But runs in sequence. We can improve it to run in parallel like this:

```js
let results = []

async function makeApiCalls () {
  const promises = []

  // fire all requests
  for (const apiUrl in apiUrls) {
    promises.push(apiCall(apiUrl))
  }

  // wait until all promises are resolved and copy responses to array
  results = [...await Promise.all(promises)];

  console.log(results) // [data, someData, otherData...] 
}

makeApiCalls()
```

Comment: are you using any library to make ajax call? can you provide the fiddle?

Comment: Are you attempting to inspect the value of `stats` immediately after this perhaps?  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) and/or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) are worth a read if so.

Comment: "it seems that array ist not visible in function" — What output do you get that leads you to that conclusion?

Comment: in console i get 'pushed OK' 2 times, but array is empty

Comment: At what point are you determining the array is empty?  Can you show that code too?

Comment: if the array were not visible in the function, then the `push` would fail and the program would stop before it got to the `console.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping over asynchronous calls is not going to work very well, because you'll have no idea when you're finished and the `stats` array is populated. You need some additional machinery to handle this. Without using `async` or promises, the basic idea is:

```
var stats = [];
var finishedCount = 0;  // keep track of how many callbacks have completed

for (let i = 0; i<tempBackends.length; i++)
{

    http.get(tempBackends[i], function(res) {

        console.log("Received response: " + res.statusCode);

        if(res.statusCode == 200) {
            stats.push('OK');
            console.log('pushed OK\n');
        }
        else {
            stats.push('Not OK');
            console.log('pushed Not OK\n');
        }

        // ADD LOGIC HERE TO HANDLE ALL CALLBACKS HAVING FINISHED
        finishedCount++;
        if (finishedCount === tempBackends.length) {
          console.log("ALL DONE!! stats is", stats);
        }

    });
}
```

However, with this approach, the `stats` array is not going to be aligned with `tempBackends`. The order of the values in `stats` will be based on the order in which the asynchronous calls finished. In addition, this style of code is going to be hard to maintain. Instead, you should use `async` or promises. The `async` approach would be:

```
async.map(
  tempBackends, 
  function(backend, callback) {
    http.get(backend, function(res) {
      callback(null, res.statusCode === 200 ? "OK" : "Not OK");
    });
  function(err, data) {
    console.log("ALL DONE!! stats is", data);
  }
);
```

The promise approach is more readable and writable. First, make a promisified version of `http.get`:

```
function getPromise(backend) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    http.get(backend, function(res) {
      resolve(res.statusCode === 200 ? "OK" : "Not OK");
    });
  });
}
```

Now you can just write

```
Promise.all(tempBackends . map(getPromise)) .
  then(function(stats) {
    console.log("ALL DONE!! stats is", stats);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require('http');

var list = ['http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting',
            'http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting',
            'http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting',
            'http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting',
            'http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting'];

var responseArray = [];

var calls = function(){
  var index = 0;
  var callWithIndex = function (i){
    http.get(list[i], function(apiResponse) {
      var statusCode = apiResponse.statusCode;

      apiResponse.on('data', function(chunk) {

      });

      apiResponse.on('end', function() {
        responseArray.push(statusCode);

        i += 1;

        if(i < list.length){
          callWithIndex(i);
        } else {
          console.log(responseArray.toString());
        }

      });

    });
  };
  callWithIndex(index);
};

calls();
```

If you mess with nodejs, you should know which callback you should execute your next iteration and when you should process your data. Notice how I called the next iteration in the response.on('end') part as well as how I pushed the statusCode to the array there as well.

Answer (score -2):

Try passing your array variable `stats` inside the function, because the scope of a function is local.

`http.get(tempBackends[i], function(res,stats) {
// access stats here now
}`

Comment: This will not work at all, because `http.get` has no idea it needs to pass this array to the callback.